# How to get data menu and sub-menu in two table with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a problem. how to join 2 tables and display sub menus based on the corresponding menu ID

my database : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoCy1.png)

and my model is

```
function get_all_bantuan(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('kategori');
    $r = $this->db->get();
    return $r->result();
}

function get_isi_kategori_bantuan(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('kategori a');
    $this->db->join('menu_kategori b', 'a.id_kategori=b.id_kat');
    $this->db->where('b.status','on');
    $r = $this->db->get();
    return $r->result_array();
}
```

my controller :

```
$data['info'] = $this->Halaman_bantuan_m->get_all_bantuan();
$data['sub_info'] = $this->Halaman_bantuan_m->get_isi_kategori_bantuan();

$this->load->view('headerHelp',$data);
```

my view is :

```
<div class="row">
    <?php 
        foreach($info as $row){ 
    ?>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 dsg">
            <div class="hlp co_num1">
                <h3 class="djnl"><?php echo $row->kategori?></h3>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <?php 
                    foreach($sub_info as $row){ 
                ?>
                    <li class="ct-sub"><a href="<?php echo base_url('bantuan/');?><?php echo $row['slug'];?>"><?php echo $row['menu'];?> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play plb pull-right"></i></a></li>
                <?php }?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php }?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for where condition because there is no fields called status in your database tables.

```
return $this->db->join('menu_kategori', 'id_kategori=id_kat','left')->get('kategori')->result_array();
```